# After upsizing ms access database for distribution front-end what i have to do

Tags: ms-access-2010

I would like to know after upsizing ms access database to sql server successfully with my user name in the domain and windows authentication and linking access tables to sql server tables,

for distribution this front-end to other users in the domain what i have to do? Is enough give a copy of the front-end to other users and defining their user names and permissions in the sql server? Or it needs some vba code in ms access for defining linked tables and ODBC connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the ODBC driver you use is installed on users' machines - and, of course, Access is installed.

Table links don't change. If you didn't use Windows authentication, however, tables had to be relinked using each user's credentials.

Comment: When i did upsizing with Access 2010 i did not see ODBC driver and it's name, if it is  possible i like to link to sql server other users without installing odbc on each machine i have seen some vba code about that but i do not know step by step how to do that? I have also some misunderstanding, For example if vba can connect to sql server other users it is necessary for my self installed ODBC?

Comment: If you use DSN (the ODBC manager), the DSN entry must also exist on users' machines. If you use _DSN less connection_, only the driver must be present.

Comment: And when upsized ms access on my computer (before distributing ) is it used dsn? Can upsize ms access also dsn less? It is necessary when to upsize use dsn and then we can distribute dsn less?

Comment: Only you know your connection string and if you sat up a DSN to use.

Comment: Thanks, you mean for knowing connection string and using that for other users when i use dsn less , at first i must setup a dsn on my pc and it is necessary?

Comment: No, it isn't necessary.

Comment: My question is if we do not use dsn at the first how to link access tables to sql server tables

Comment: You create the connection string by hand. Look up _DSN less connection_ - lots of guides and tips out there.